# How to import XSD in Another XSD

Tags: java, xsd

I am attempting to import xsd to another xsd. i am seeing some problems to import. i could not understand the solutions which provided in web. below is my XSD.

I have HEADER.xsd. it is common for all other xsd's.

HEADER.XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="Header" type="reqHeader"/>

  <xs:complexType name="reqHeader">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="MsgId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="MsgDesc" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

MESSAGE1.XSD

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:import namespace="" schemaLocation="\resources\xsd\HEADER.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />

  <xs:element name="Message">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>

        <xs:element name="Header" type="xs:reqHeader" />

        <xs:element name="Body">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="User">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Name" minOccurs="1"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:int" name="DOB" minOccurs="1"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Here i am trying to import element called  since it is common for all xsd's [MESSAGE1.XSD MESSAGE2.XSD and so on].

Exception says : Is not a valid:src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'xs:reqHeader'. It was detected that 'xs:reqHeader' is in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', but components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'file:/D:/Projects/workspace/Message/resources/xsd/MESSAGE1.xsd'. If this is the incorrect namespace, perhaps the prefix of 'xs:reqHeader' needs to be changed. If this is the correct namespace, then an appropriate 'import' tag should be added to 'file:/D:/Projects/workspace/Message/resources/xsd/MESSAGE1.XSD'.

**My Project structure is :**

/src/com

/lib

/resources/xsd/MESSAGE1.XSD

Please someone help me to resolve it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bingo! After fighting a lot with the XSDs I have found an error free way:

Here's the code:

- You need to change the `xs:import` to `xs:include`
- Remove the `namespace=""` and the `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` from the `xs:include` line

MESSAGE1.xsd

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:include schemaLocation="header.xsd" />

<xs:element name="Message">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>

            <xs:element name="Header" type="reqHeader" />

            <xs:element name="Body">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="User">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Name" minOccurs="1" />
                                    <xs:element type="xs:int" name="DOB" minOccurs="1" />
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

HEADER.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="Header" type="reqHeader" />

<xs:complexType name="reqHeader">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="MsgId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="MsgDesc" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Please modify the XSD location according to your local file's location.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry.. i have corrected.. but still i have the same problem.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: compilation exception occurs :  when adding <xs:element name="Header" type="xs:reqHeader"/>

src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'xs:reqHeader'. It was detected that 'xs:reqHeader' is in 
 namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', but components from this namespace are not referenceable 
 from schema document 'file:///D:/Projects/workspace/Message/resources/xsd/HEADER.xsd'

Comment: Changed the answer. Works fine in my Eclipse.

Comment: Updated the answer. In the code, please change the XSD folder location according to your local drive structure.

Comment: It works really thanks.. we need to provide absolute path in <xs:include schemaLocation="header.xsd" /> ? Please advise..

Comment: Both works. If you are using Relative path, then you need to write like <xs:include schemaLocation="res/header.xsd" /> where 'res' is a folder where the XSD is residing and this folder is at the same level of the folder from where you are referencing it. If you are giving Absolute path, then you need to write <xs:include schemaLocation="file:D:/workspace/Test/res/header.xsd" /> Remember to add the 'file:' before adding the location.

Comment: Also, make sure that the `<xs:include … />` element is at the beginning of the including file. Otherwise you may encounter a `element include: Schemas parser error` error message.