# Generate wsdl from xsd using common property from common xsd file

Tags: web-services, spring-boot, soap, wsdl

I have to generate separate wsdl for separate client.

1. entry.xsd -> entry.wsdl
2. migration.xsd -> migration.wsdl

I am using spring boot contract frist approach for generating wsdl from xsd definition. Problem is type are same for both xsd fiels like: credential, so I want to create a common xsd file and include/import in both xsd so can reduce redundant code.

like common.xsd -> entry.xsd, migration.xsd

but getting exception or soap client giving invalid error message.

Any help, how to generate wsdl from two xsd where one is base xsd file?

It's giving, failed to update interface. InvalidFormatException from SOAP Client.

**entry.sxd**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:tns="http://www.test.com/idms-ws"
           targetNamespace="http://www.test.com/idms-ws"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:include schemaLocation="common-element.xsd"></xs:include>

<xs:element name="updateMigrationStatusRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="credential" type="tns:credential" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="referenceNo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**common-element.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">


    <xs:complexType name="credential">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="loginName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="password" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Did you try that ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41606718/how-to-import-xsd-in-another-xsd

Comment: Checking brother.

Comment: I have tried. But can't generate endpoints from SOAP client. I have edited the questions, can you please check??